# what does "Let tomorrow wait its turn, today still has tonight on its side" mean?

Tags: meaning, literature

> Let tomorrow wait its turn, today still has tonight on its side.

What does that mean?

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fL8ddOqPjk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The straightforward meaning is *to let tomorrow wait because today isn't finished yet (there's still tonight)*. Beyond that, you haven't given enough context for a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you but The full contextis in the scene in the commercial video.. Can you check it please. Btw what is "Deadlines draft" mean at 0:26 in the video?

Comment: Sorry, on this site, it is expected that all relevant information is presented in the question or the answer post. The purpose of links here is mainly to allow verification of statements made. This is because the site aims to be a long-term repository, and linked information often changes or gets deleted or becomes inaccessible over time. Please supply context within your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

> Let tomorrow waits its turn, today still has tonight on its side.

I understand it like a carpe diem. It is *now is all that you have for sure, enjoy it!*
and

> deadline draft

I understand like *your projects or whatever span their time and then you can chill out.*